# Laravel site showing 500 error after redirecting to https from cpanel

Tags: cpanel, internal-server-error, server-error

**I tried redirecting a Laravel site to https from cpanel and now the site shows 500 error.**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@abc.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**This is the .htaccess file :**

```
RewriteOptions inherit
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I tried redirecting a Laravel site to https from cpanel and now the site shows 500 error.I know no prior coding and only have access to cpanel